# Prevent ajaxComplete outside click element

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

When clicking on `ajax_add_to_cart` button this should happen: element `added_to_cart` appears and appends after a `go to checkout` button.

It does its job, but it's not able to keep the event within its own click element. So when you click for `#product1` and after that `#product2` it executes for both the ajaxComplete event and appends `a.checkout` multiple times.

I tried the follwing:

- `global: false;` after `ajaxComplete`.
- exchange after if-statement `'.added_to_cart'` with `this`, this causes an error

**HTML**

```
<div id="product1"><button class="ajax_add_to_cart">Add to Cart</button></div>
<div id="product2"><button class="ajax_add_to_cart">Add to Cart</button></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.ajax_add_to_cart').click(function(){
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        if( jQuery('.added_to_cart').length > 0 ) {
            jQuery('.added_to_cart').after('<a href="/checkout/" class="added_to_cart wc-forward checkout-btn">Go to Checkout</a>');
        }
    });
});
```

How do you hook the ajaxComplete function to its own click function and doesn't call other ajax calls?

The reason I use ajaxComplete, because WC uses by default Ajax to add the `added_to_cart` button and I would like the appended element to come with it.

Comment: Your question seems to actually be asking 'how do I not append the `a` element if there's already one visible?' If that's the case, just change `> 0` to `=== 0`. If that's not what you're asking, can you please edit the question to be more clear as your description of 'keeping the event within its own click element' doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 'keeping the event within its own click element' is explained in the next sentence. It's about to avoid that the appended element is appearing multiple times when ajax is completed in different sections on the page.

Comment: Which is why I assumed your question is actually what I stated in my first comment, and the answer is there too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no it's not about "if there is already one visible'. It needs to append when it's visible after the ajax event. This is the follow up:

- click
- ajaxComplete
- added_to_cart = visible? yes > append anchor.

Above works for 1 btn, but with 2 btns not. When btn #1 has already been clicked (its anchor is visible) and you click on button #2 (with no anchor visible yet) it adds an anchor on both buttons.

If not clear, please follow [this page](https://showmy.website/haaranalyse/), and click the different "in winkelwagen" buttons.